# How can I block rotation to only allow portrait mode in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, device-orientation

I need to block rotation on a **specific page** and this has to work both for Android and iOS.

I tried using NuGet Plugin.DeviceOrientation and adding the following code

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (CrossDeviceOrientation.IsSupported) 
                CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.LockOrientation(Plugin.DeviceOrientation.Abstractions.DeviceOrientations.Portrait);
        }


protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            if (CrossDeviceOrientation.IsSupported) 
                CrossDeviceOrientation.Current.UnlockOrientation();
        }
```

but throws exception:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: iOS or Android?  Did you include the plugin in both the shard and platform projects?

Comment: both, and plugin is include for both too

Comment: https://github.com/wcoder/Xamarin.Plugin.DeviceOrientation/issues/22

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package Plugin.CurrentActivity 2.1.0.4 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Plugin.CurrentActivity 2.1.0.4 supports: monoandroid44 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Xamarin.Forms, you could dependency service.

**Create a interface:**

```
 public interface IRotate
{
    void ForcePortrait();
}
```

**Android:**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(RoateHandler))]
namespace RotatePage.Droid
{
class RoateHandler : IRotate
{
    public void ForcePortrait()
    {
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
}
```

**iOS:**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(RoateImplementation))]
namespace RotatePage.iOS
{
class RoateImplementation : IRotate
{
    public void ForcePortrait()
    {
        UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
    }
}
}
```

**Usage:**

DependencyService.Get().ForcePortrait();

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'RoateHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I thought "Roate" was a typo but tried "Rotate" and error too haha. Do I have to  add a Nuget or reference?

Comment: The `RoateHandler` is created in Android part. I have uploded my project. You could check on GitHub. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/RotatePage

Comment: Thanks, I was able to try it, for blocks all pages, not only the ones where I use the line DependencyService.Get<IRotate>().ForcePortrait();

Comment: Modify the answer with exactly what I was looking for :)