# How to rotate screen manual as well automatic in Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, orientation, orientation-changes

I have a requirement to rotate the screen to Landscape from Portrait. Then I should stay in Landscape even though I have not tilted my phone. Portrait and Landscape have different views with buttons for orientation change and is in same content page which I have handled with content template. So, now I wanted to rotate automatically if I tilt the phone or if I tap on the button in either view to change orientation.

1. Portrait -> Landscape change using button then I should stay in landscape view until one rotation happen.
2. ex:- Now, I came to Landscape using a sensor, and I am in Landscape mode if I tap the button for rotation then I should change in portrait and should stay there.

I want to satisfy both cases. How to achieve that in Android and iOS (**Xamarin.Forms**)?

Anyone faces this kind of usecase and if you got a solution. Help me out.

Answer (score 2):

When using Xamarin.Forms, the supported method of controlling device orientation is to use the settings for each individual project.

You could call the following method in dependency service.

Create a interface:

```
  public interface IOrientationService
{
    void Landscape();
    void Portrait();
}
```

**Android:**

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
public void Landscape()
{
    ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
}

public void Portrait()
{
    ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}
}
```

**iOS:**

```
 public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
 public void Landscape()
{
    AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));   
}

public void Portrait()
{
    AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
}
}
```

For the usage of dependency service, you could refer to the link below. [How can I block rotation to only allow portrait mode in xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63732800/xamarin-forms-block-rotation-only-portrait-view)

> 1. I want to rotate only one page in my app automatically and as well as manually.

When you do the navigation, you could do the Orientation before loading the page in `OnAppearing` event.

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        DependencyService.Get<IOrientationService>().Landscape();
    }
```

> 2. Both portrait and landscape views are different.

Liek 1., you could set the Orientation you want to in each page with `OnAppearing()` event.

> 3. I should not lock the particular page at any cause but I also when I want to change orientation manually I should able to do that. Even though I am not rotating/tilt the phone.

If you want to do it manually, invoke the `Landscape` or `Portrait` in a click event or tap or something else.

Comment: My requirement is not this. To make it clear I will mention the following. 

1. I want to rotate only one page in my app automatically and as well as manually. 

2. Both portrait and landscape views are different. 

3. I should not lock the particular page at any cause but I also when I want to change orientation manually I should able to do that. Even though I am not rotating/tilt the phone.

Comment: Both pages are control template I mean which I am using inside the content page. So, one template should design for portrait and other one for landscape. 

Simple example, If I hold the phone in portrait and click the button to change landscape template it should show Landscape view. But actually its not actually rotated. So what I have did is I designed one  view which will show landscape view in portrait and rotated all the controls. Its possible if the page has less no of control. To overcome this, anyone have any solution.

Comment: Provide your code of what you have tried not only for the description.